# Is it possible to send emails with google api without g suite?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I read this article at medium https://medium.com/lyfepedia/sending-emails-with-gmail-api-and-python-49474e32c81f about sending emails with the google api, but i wonder if i need a g suite account for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Oauth2 to authenticate your application and use the Gmail api, note verification of a gmail application is not cheep and you will probably not be able to run it very long unverified.

Service account authentication is only possible using gsuite domain wide delegation and will only work on the domain email accounts.   There is no way to use service account authentication with a normal gmail account.

Depending upon what you are doing you might want to look into going though the smtp imap server rather than the gmail api.

Comment: I need to send the mails from the server, so i guess its only possible with suite, correct?

Comment: Service accounts require Gsuite Oauth2 does not.  You can use Oauth2 authenticate your application once and save the refresh token use the refresh token to request a new access token every time the server needs to access the data.