# Can I use Gmail API send email without Google Workspace (or Service accounts)?

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I want to use Gmail API to send email in JAVA,and all information I fond told me to create a  Service accounts and connect with Google Workspace. But I don't have a  Google Workspace account also can't register one,so the question is:

1.Can I send email without  Google Workspace?

2.Can I just Add 'type' into Client ID.json to make it work like  Service accounts.json?

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906104/is-it-possible-to-send-emails-with-google-api-without-g-suite). Please use the search function the next time!:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send emails with google api without g suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906104/is-it-possible-to-send-emails-with-google-api-without-g-suite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I send email without Google Workspace?

Yes you can use gmail api without workspace you will just need to use Oauth2 rather than a service account and authorize a user.

Oauth2 requires that a user consent to the access to their google account.  A user will need to authorize your code at least once.

Where as service accounts allow you to preauthroize access defined using domain wide delegation within a google workspace account. So no user interaction would be required.

> Can I just Add 'type' into Client ID.json to make it work like Service accounts.json?

No the code is different depending upon the type of client you have created. If you create a web client then you need to use code designed for a web client. If you create installed client credentials then you need to use the code for an installed client.

The following sample [Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) is designed for an installed app. It will open the browser consent window on the machine the code is running on.

Comment: Oauth2 can work. Thanks a lot!